# Convert iCalendar DateTime to Java Date object

Tags: java, date, datetime, icalendar

I have iCalendar DateTime value in UTC format **20160217T121209Z**. Can someone tell me how I can parse and convert this in to Java Date object which also contains the time values as well ?

Update: My final value, when I print date must be something like this :

Wed Feb 17 12:12:09 CET 2016

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please don't forget to interprete the trailing Z as UTC+00:00 which is ISO-8601-standard.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss'Z'");
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
java.util.Date d = sdf.parse("20151217T174218Z");
System.out.println(d); // output in your system timezone using toString()
```

If you are on Java-7 or later you can also use the pattern "yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmssX" and omit the second line setting the UTC reference.

Comment: Please see my update, I do not want to print T and Z and want to have the results in normal java date object format

Comment: @Hoysala Yes, my solution yields this standard representation ("Thu Dec 17 18:42:18 CET 2015"). The first line of my answer was rather addressed to the wrong contribution of Rahul Tripathi.

Answer (score 2):

This is how you can convert iCalendar DateTime to Java Date object.
Assuming icalendar date as **20151217T174218Z**.

```
        String icalvalue = "20151217T174218Z";
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
                "yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss'Z'");
        dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
        Date date = null;
        try {
            date = dateFormat.parse(icalvalue);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(date);
```